# Monitor status of GET request Python

Tags: python, api, url

I have one url http://abc.def.com/something which I access and it returns a status message in the form of a JSON library. From this JSON library, I need to retrieve the value of the field 'fileDownloadURL', but on first attempt this is always the empty string. Therefore, I need to access a different URL http://abc.def.com/something_else which returns a new JSON library with the same fields as the first one, but after a while the value of 'fileDownloadURL' is no longer empty.

This works well in any of my browsers, but when I try to do it in Python, the 'fileDownloadURL' value returned by the second URL keeps being empty. I think this is because my browser sends some information about who I am to the URLs, but I am not sending this information in Python.

How can I get the server to realize that it is the same person accessing both URLs?

Sample code is

```
import urllib2, base64, json, time

base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
request = urllib2.Request("http://abc.def.com/something")
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)

url_response_json = urllib2.urlopen(request)

url_response_dict = json.load(url_response_json)

fileDownloadURL = url_response_dict["fileDownloadURL"]

status_url = urllib2.Request("http://abc.def.com/something_else")
status_url.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)


while fileDownloadURL == '':
    url_status_json = urllib2.urlopen(status_url)
    url_status_dict = json.load(url_status_json)
    fileDownloadURL = url_status_dict["fileDownloadURL"] 
    time.sleep(3)
```

This code never breaks out of the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The code never breaks out of the while loop because you are never resetting the value of `fileDownloadURL`. Try this in your while loop:

```
while fileDownloadURL == '':
    url_status_json = urllib2.urlopen(status_url)
    url_status_dict = json.load(url_status_json)
    fileDownloadURL = url_status_dict["fileDownloadURL"] 
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have that already. Missed it in my copy-paste. It is actually because the new URL does not return a value.

Comment: Then you need to try this with the requests library. It has automatic keep-alive on connections and support for sessions. Without knowing the urls, I can't test it, but I'd bet that it will solve your problems.